# I want to build a website like Tesla's (or any car company's) custom build and configure system. What's the best framework?

Tags: angular, wordpress, web, web-frameworks

The website/web app needs to have a login system. Users will need to login, customize their car, save and come back another day. When they are done, they place an order and pay via Stripe. Maybe in the future, they can manage their custom cars via a dashboard.

This is an example of what I want to build but with a login system https://www.tesla.com/en_au/model3/design

**Which framework would be the most suitable for this kind of system and why?**

I already have knowledge of Angular and Wordpress. I am willing to learn a new framework if it's better.
I would personally prefer Angular since its quite fast to develop and does not need server configuration, it can run entirely on Firebase, unlike Wordpress.
With Wordpress, I have little experience, but I find it hard to use WP databases for things like these (Eg. Storing user data, etc). Or maybe I don't have enough knowledge about this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **Wordpress** is a content manager ! We can not give it the title of a framework. 
 
**Angular** is a real **front-end framework**, where you could implement your business intelligence. The output of Angular is a **SPA (Single Page Application)** which personaly I think it is the *best adapted to your case*.

**Why** ! Because you will need to download all the app in the browser before starting using it so the user experience would be continue and without any interruption. 
That is my personal opinion. Best of luck !

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I thought, SPA is what I should go with. 
ReactJS, Ember.js, Vue.js also output SPAs. Do you have experience with any of these? If so, which one do you prefer?

Comment: I personally work with Angular. I like it so far. To have a quick start I advice Angular.